# How to get all the Runbook jobs in SQL Azure using powershell

Tags: sql-server, azure, powershell, azure-powershell

I want to list all the Azure Automation Jobs that are present in Runbook using Powershell.

How can I do this?
Can someone provide me the command for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use this [`Get-AzAutomationJob`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.automation/get-azautomationjob?view=azps-1.8.0) command.

Sample:

Get all jobs for a runbook:

```
Get-AzAutomationJob -AutomationAccountName "Contoso17" -ResourceGroupName "ResourceGroup01" -RunbookName "Runbook02"
```

Get all runbook jobs in an automation account:

```
Get-AzAutomationJob -AutomationAccountName "Contoso17" -ResourceGroupName "ResourceGroup01"
```